# How to attach to a systemd service from an ssh connection

Tags: ssh, systemd, io-redirection

I want to attach and control a systemd service like I do on a normal terminal, that's because my process running as a service has an input console and I'd want to be able to access that. I saw other solutions redirecting the stdin/stdout of the process to a tty using systemd configuration and then attaching with a tools like conspy or reptyr, but these don't work over an SSH connection. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Pwease 

Answer (score 0):

If you do `man systemctl` you'll find this option:

```
-H, --host=
           Execute the operation remotely. Specify a hostname, or a username and
           hostname separated by "@", to connect to. The hostname may optionally
           be suffixed by a container name, separated by ":", which connects
           directly to a specific container on the specified host. This will use
           SSH to talk to the remote machine manager instance. Container names
           may be enumerated with machinectl -H HOST.
```

This will allow you to perform any actions on a service on a remote machine that you could if you were local ( permitting you are working as a user with elevated permissions to do so ).

Comment: Sorry I don't think I explained well what I'm looking for. The service i'm using has an input console and I want to be able to access that when the service is running, I see that from the question only it may not be obvious. I'll edit it now.